# How can I get and store a changing version number from a Jenkins build using a cURL command?

Tags: bash, curl, jenkins, deb

I'm trying to extract the name of a file with the latest version number so I can move it to another directory using bash.  I have a directory called "deb-files" that I'd like to move the downloaded .deb file into. This is a basic version of what I'm looking for:

```
if [ "$REPOSITORY_NAME" = "repository" ];
    then : curl https://example.com/$REPOSITORY_NAME*.deb

    mv $REPOSITORY_NAME*.deb ./deb-files/;
```

$REPOSITORY_NAME is populated by user input. Please just assume that they input "repository". Note that the file name is the same name as the repository name. I thought putting a star in front of the extension meant "latest version", but every time I run it, I get an error at the mv part of the code which says it cannot find the file - "No such file or directory".  Any ideas?  I've tried escaping the star and quoting the variable name.  No luck.

In case it matters, I'm trying to access artifacts created by a build in Jenkins.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Neither curl nor the Jenkins server understand the shell wildcard '*'. You'll have to find the exact name of the artifact that you want to download.

One way is to modify the Jenkins job to create (and archive as an artifact) a symbolic link to the artifact with a fixed name (*pkg1_latest.deb*).

Another way is to use the Jenkins REST API to get information about the latest build, but to do this generally, you'll need to parse some JSON.

```
curl http://jenkins:8080/job/JOB_NAME/lastSuccessfulBuild/api/json?tree=artifacts[*]
```

Generates something like:

```
{
  "artifacts" : [
    {
      "displayPath" : "platformA/pkg1_VERSION.deb",
      "fileName" : "pkg1_VERSION.deb",
      "relativePath" : "build/platformA/pkg1_VERSION.deb"
    },
    {
      "displayPath" : "platformB/pkg1_VERSION.deb",
      "fileName" : "pkg1_VERSION.deb",
      "relativePath" : "build/platformB/pkg1_VERSION.deb"
    },
    ...
  ]
}
```

Then parse the output to find the appropriate relative path. With the relative path, you can retrieve the artifact:

```
curl http://jenkins:8080/job/JOB_NAME/lastSuccessfulBuild/artifact/$relpath
```

**Update:** Yet another solution is to download a zip archive containing *all* artifacts, and extract the ones you're interested in.

```
curl "http://jenkins:8080/job/JOB_NAME/lastSuccessfulBuild/artifact/*zip*/archive.zip
unzip archive.zip "$REPOSITORY_PATH*.deb"
```

The special `*zip*` in the URL tells Jenkins to create a zip archive of everything.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this!